# Dataframe Sliding index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, window, rolling-computation, sliding-window

I have the following dataframe with index in datetime:

```
        A
date      
2020-01  1
2020-01  2
2020-02  3
2020-02  4
2020-03  5
2020-03  6
2020-04  7
2020-04  8
```

I want to create a for loop returning new dataframes (until end of data) with this outcome:

**dataframe1**

```
         A
date      
2020-01  1
2020-01  2
2020-02  3
2020-02  4
```

**dataframe2**

```
2020-02  3
2020-02  4
2020-03  5
2020-03  6
```

**dataframe3**

```
2020-03  5
2020-03  6
2020-04  7
2020-04  8
```

The idea is an 'add and drop' rolling. The logic is:

- take first two months and return dataframe1
- drop first month and add a new one to return dataframe2
- continue until end of data

I have found [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to be useful, however I do not know how to implement it properly. I have tried and when I do the rolling, the values of each month are **summed up**. I want to keep the original values!

Also, If I use a simple for loop like:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(df[i : i+n])
```

I can achieve my outcome according to **the length** of my dataframe. But how actually do it according to **months**?

Any suggestion would be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57853302/6361531

Comment: @ScottBoston thank you for providing this link. I am trying to follow the loop solution provided, however when I do **pd.date_range(start='2020-01', end='2020-04)**, I get only the index dates **in Arrays: (['2020-01', '2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-03', '2020-04', '2020-04'`)]**

Comment: Any advise on how to actually get also column 'A' values in pd dataframe format  (not in arrays) ? Really appreciated your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
import pandas as pd 
d = {'date': ['2020-01','2020-01','2020-02','2020-02','2020-03','2020-03','2020-04','2020-04',], 'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m')
result=[]
for date in df.date.unique():
    result.append(df[(df['date']>=date)&(df['date']<=pd.to_datetime(date)+pd.DateOffset(months=1))])
```

Out :

```
    for x in result:
        print(x)
    
        date  A
0 2020-01-01  1
1 2020-01-01  2
2 2020-02-01  3
3 2020-02-01  4
        date  A
2 2020-02-01  3
3 2020-02-01  4
4 2020-03-01  5
5 2020-03-01  6
        date  A
4 2020-03-01  5
5 2020-03-01  6
6 2020-04-01  7
7 2020-04-01  8
        date  A
6 2020-04-01  7
7 2020-04-01  8
```

Comment: Hi Mathieu, I have successfully adjusted to my df and it works amazing thanks!

Comment: Before ticking the question as completed, I have a last question: if I want to drop and take 2 or more months at time (rather than 1), how should I modify the code accordingly?

Comment: I get it should be done something here --> **(df['date']>=date)&(df['date']<=pd.to_datetime(date)**. But I have been playing with it and I have not figured out yet. So if you have an idea, please let me know and thank you!

Comment: warning, always put pd.to_datetime in this code juste before date. If you want to rolling with a bigger interval for example 3 months, you just have to change this part pd.DateOffset(months=1)

Comment: Thank you for replying back. I am not referring to the interval ** pd.DateOffset(months)**, but I was wondering if there is a way to change the window (in window) that will be added and dropped each time. For example, if I set **pd.DateOffset(months=2)** the starting interval will be **2020-01 ... 2020-03**, then next df will be **2020-02... 2020-04** and so on by **dropping 1** month and **adding 1** month. I was wondering that instead we could modify this feature.

Comment: For example, if  I set **pd.DateOffset(months=14)** and I want to **add/drop 3 months**, it should return: 1st df --> **2020-01 ... 2021-03**; 2nd df --> **2020-04 ... 2021-06**; 3rd df --> **2020-07 ... 2021-09***; 4th df --> **2020-10 ... 2021-12** , and so on. In other words, dropping 1/4 and adding next 1/4. Hope I was clear enough and thank you so much!

Comment: and this is why I have mentioned --> **(df['date']>=date)&(df['date']<=pd.to_datetime(date)**

Answer (score 1):

Ok i get what you want ! try this :

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
d = {'date': ['2020-01','2020-01','2020-02','2020-02','2020-03','2020-03','2020-04','2020-04',], 'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m')
result=[]
for i,date in enumerate(df.date.unique()):
    if i==0:
        result.append(df[(df['date']>=date)&(df['date']<=pd.to_datetime(date)+pd.DateOffset(months=2))])
    else:
        try:
            result.append(df[(df['date']>result[i-1].iloc[-1,:].date)&(df['date']<=result[i-1].iloc[-1,:].date+pd.DateOffset(months=2))])
        except:pass
result = [i for i in result if not i.empty] 
for res in result:
    print(res)
```

Here i look in the previous df to add a condition on date. It will be > than the last date of the last dataframe.

```
df
Out[248]: 
        date  A
0 2020-01-01  1
1 2020-01-01  2
2 2020-02-01  3
3 2020-02-01  4
4 2020-03-01  5
5 2020-03-01  6
6 2020-04-01  7
7 2020-04-01  8

for res in result:
    print(res)

        date  A
0 2020-01-01  1
1 2020-01-01  2
2 2020-02-01  3
3 2020-02-01  4
4 2020-03-01  5
5 2020-03-01  6
        date  A
6 2020-04-01  7
7 2020-04-01  8
```

EDIT :

```
result=[]
for i,date in enumerate(df.date.unique()):
    if i==0:
        result.append(df[(df['date']>=date)&(df['date']<=pd.to_datetime(date)+pd.DateOffset(months=14))]) #here you choose your time period (for the first df 14 months like in your exemple)
    else:
        try:
            result.append(df[(df['date']>result[i-1].iloc[0,:].date+pd.DateOffset(months=3))&(df['date']<=result[i-1].iloc[0,:].date+pd.DateOffset(months=17))]) #here for the others df, you take all the row between the first date of the previous dataframe + 3 months and the first date of the previous dataframe + 14+3 months
        except:pass
result = [i for i in result if not i.empty] 
for res in result:
    print(res)
```

Comment: Okay, we are almost there :). Now referring to my previous example, by setting **pd.DateOffset(months=14)**, we start with df **2020-01 ... 2021-03**, and then if I set **pd.DateOffset(months=3)** in the **try:** statement, it will return next data frames by 3 months each: **2021-04 ... 2021-06**, then **2021-07 ... 2021-09**, etc... and this is great!

Comment: however, I do not want to drop all previous data, I just want to drop the first three months!  so, instead of returning the 2nd df like **2021-04** ... 2021-06, it should return **2020-04** .. 2021-06, so actually keeping the same fixed window gap of **months=14**. Hope I was clear and again thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: You can try my edit, i havn't test it at the moment

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, let's create a dictionary of dataframes using rolling of index values like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

# Create and read in dummy dataframe
txtfile = StringIO("""        A
date      
2020-01  1
2020-01  2
2020-02  3
2020-02  4
2020-03  5
2020-03  6
2020-04  7
2020-04  8
2020-05  9
""")
df = pd.read_csv(txtfile, index_col=0,sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

# Use `pd.factorize` to create the position of each of the periods
pos, ldates = pd.factorize(df.index)


# Create pd.Series from a unique list of those positions
s = pd.Series(np.arange(pos.max()+1))

# Use this rolling-apply trick to create a sliding window of indexes positions
l_of_idx = []
s.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: l_of_idx.append(x.astype(int).tolist()) or 0)
# Note: the 2 in rolling indicates two months in this example

# Create a dictionary of dataframes for each of those windows
d_dfs = {n:df.loc[ldates[i]] for n,i in enumerate(l_of_idx)}

#Output each dataframe:
print('First dataframe:')
print(d_dfs[0])
print('\nSecond dataframe')
print(d_dfs[1])
print('\nThird dataframe')
print(d_dfs[2])
print('\nFourth dataframe')
print(d_dfs[3])
```

Output dictionary values:

```
First dataframe:
         A
date      
2020-01  1
2020-01  2
2020-02  3
2020-02  4

Second dataframe
         A
date      
2020-02  3
2020-02  4
2020-03  5
2020-03  6

Third dataframe
         A
date      
2020-03  5
2020-03  6
2020-04  7
2020-04  8

Fourth dataframe
         A
date      
2020-04  7
2020-04  8
2020-05  9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.  I used @ScottBoston's definition of df, then I converted the index to Datetime `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Then, I created a PeriodIndex for the entire date range; zip the PeriodIndex with an offset of itself (to get start and end dates); and stored results in a list.

```
# create unique sorted list of periods in the data set
idx = pd.period_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq='M')

months_in_window = 2
d_dfs = list()

# extract window from original data frame
for start, end in zip(idx, idx[months_in_window - 1:]):
    d_dfs.append(df[start.start_time : end.end_time])
    
descs = ['First dataframe:', 'Second dataframe:', 
         'Third dataframe:', 'Fourth dataframe:']

for desc, d_df in zip(descs, d_dfs):
    print(desc)
    print(d_df, end='\n\n')

First dataframe:
            A
date         
2020-01-01  1
2020-01-01  2
2020-02-01  3
2020-02-01  4

Second dataframe:
            A
date         
2020-02-01  3
2020-02-01  4
2020-03-01  5
2020-03-01  6

Third dataframe:
            A
date         
2020-03-01  5
2020-03-01  6
2020-04-01  7
2020-04-01  8

Fourth dataframe:
            A
date         
2020-04-01  7
2020-04-01  8
2020-05-01  9
```